# Papers on Prompt Engineering

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, papers, language-model, gpt-3

I am into AI in general and NLP in particular. Besides, I have a background in philosophy, and the new LLMs like GPT-3 seem to have exciting capabilities. I want to study prompt engineering (for example, teaching the model to reason, etc.)

Do you know any specific papers to start? I am looking for studies on the techniques of prompt engineering.

Comment: I've reformulated the title because the previous title asked for "best paper" and that can lead to opinions. In fact, this post was voted to be closed as "opinion-based".

Comment: This should help https://github.com/rynst/awesome-llm-engineering

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I am referring to the following links. They have a good number of papers and they are categorized too.

https://github.com/thunlp/PromptPapers

https://github.com/zjunlp/PromptKG

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24165)